# React Native app installled but not visible on home screen or app screen

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm working on a react-native project, and I've run into an error. I can install the app on my phone using `react-native run-android`, it installs the app on my phone and launches it. The problem is that the app is not visible on the home screen or app menu, so if I close the app, I have to re-download the app again from CLI. According to settings the app is installed and is taking up memory, but it's not present on the home screen or the app menu.

I have tried to create APK's as well and download them on my phone, but I have the same problem. The app is downloaded and installed, but the open button is grayed out, and there's still no sign on the app on neither the home screen or the app menu.

[image: App present in settings]
[image: App NOT present in app menu]

Comment: Check the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Inside the `<application>` element there should be an `<activity>` element, inside that a `<intent-filter>` element and inside that: `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` This is required in order for the app to show up.

Comment: I checked, and the launcher intent is already there. so thats not the problem

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I didn't really get to the source of the problem, it went away after I messed around and updated/upgraded gradle files

Comment: What version of React Native and Gradle did you settle on? And did you update gradle files via Android Studio?

Comment: I have faced this issue, when I enabled deep linking for my app. I have kept `android.intent.action.VIEW`, 'android.intent.category.DEFAULT` in the same `intent-filter` tag where I have `action.MAIN` and `category.LAUNCHER`. Once I have separated those into two `intent-filter`s solves the problem. I don't know why it didn't work with one `intent-filter` tag.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem and the issue is that i put `<data android:scheme="@string/facebook_app_id" />` inside the same intent-filter as action and category.

Just take data out and put it in another intent-filter like:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</intent-filter>
```

Thats solve the problem for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is here in `AndroidManifest.xml` file on `<intent-filter>`, remove any `<data>` tag inside the `<intent-filter>` block and the problem is solved.